# Sorting generated rows tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablesorter

Currently I have a script that gets information from the database after typing (500ms). The first time when I give in a parameter it's completely working but the second time if I give an other parameter it doesn't do things right. When I click the headers of the table it add like 15 rows, however I first delete them and my limit on my query is 5 rows.

How to fix this ?

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script>

            jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                jQuery("#myTable").tablesorter();
            });

            var delay = (function() {
                var timer = 0;
                return function(callback, ms) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
                };
            })();

            $(document).on("keypress", "#searchValue", function() {


                delay(function() {


                    $("#myTable tbody").empty();
                    var name = $("#searchValue").val();
                    $.post("<?php echo site_url('project/searchProject'); ?>",
                            {
                                name: name

                            },
                    function(data, status) {
                        var items = "";
                        data = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (data.toString() !== "") {
                            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                                items += "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Code + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.Description + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.ProjectLeader + "</td>";
                                items += "<td>" + item.AccountManager + "</td>";
                                items += "</tr>";

                            });
                        }
                        $("#myTable tbody").append(items);


                    });

                }, 500);

            });

        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <input type='text' name='searchValue' id='searchValue'/>

        <br>
        <br>


        <table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Project leader</th>
                    <th>Account manager</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you append the results to the tbody after each request. Do you remove duplicate entries or merge them somehow?

Comment: I remove all rows from the table with .empty() before making a request.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out update on tabelsorter.

After appending items do this :

```
$("#myTable").trigger("update");
```

Don't got bugs anymore.